# mysql: converting varchar specific format date to DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have this format stored in a varchar of mysql: Month Year

I storage it in catalan, spanish or english culture.

For example:

```
ca-ES => MAI 2019
es-ES => MAY 2019
en-GB => MAY 2019
```

or:

```
ca-ES => GEN 2019
es-ES => ENE 2019
en-GB => JAN 2019
```

I need to convert to  '1/5/2019 00:00:00' (first case) or '1/1/2019 00:00' (second case)

How can I convert in MySql to DateTime? the day is not important, and the hour.

I tested next functions:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('MAY 2019', '%W %D %M %Y') shippeddate;
```

it is returning null.

[image]

Comment: Try `Str_to_date()` function. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: it comming back with null

Comment: what query you exactly tried. Edit the question and add those details to the question also, with input and then output as well

Comment: done. I edited with the result what I tested with : select STR_TO_DATE('MAY 2019', '%W %D %M %Y') shippeddate;

Comment: str_to_date I deleted %W and %d looks like working in english culture but not in catalan or spanish... returning null, how can I change the culture in STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: you will need to set locale. Pls refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html

Comment: I had to use a "dictionary" and convert my cultures to english and then to use STR_TO_DATE to convert it to DATE

Answer (score -1):

Alone STR_TO_DATE will not work for you. You first need to use it to convert it into desired date format, then use DATE_FORMAT function to achieve the correct result-

```
select date_format(str_to_date('01 May 2019', '%d %b %Y'), '%d/%m/%y') shippeddate;
```

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d97f0d018cd27ae877515b41e8d233c).

Comment: when I set culture, catalan or spanish it doesnt work. return null when I have ENE 2019 (in spanish) or GEN 2019 (in catalan). works in english. Anyway STR_TO_DATE works for me anyway with the same case of the culture.

Comment: When I run https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9848742c4285c0fca4dec93c7c627d78,, it gives me the month name as `set` not the 'GEN'. Thats why you are getting it as null.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT returns VARCHAR and I need DATE field. I made a dictionary to translate it to english and then I used STR_TO_DATE... working ok